# Mac keyboard binding: deleteWordForward not working

Tags: macos, key-bindings

I have the following code in my `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file:

```
{
    "~f"        = "moveWordForward:";               /* M-f          Move forward word */
    "~b"        = "moveWordBackward:";              /* M-b          Move backward word */
    "~d"        = "deleteWordForward:";             /* M-d          Delete word forward */
}
```

The first two, `M-f` and `M-b` works as intended to move forward/backward one word, but the `M-d` button doesn't (it doesn't do anything). How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Possibly useful discussion here: https://gist.github.com/trusktr/1e5e516df4e8032cbc3d

Comment: FWIW, I also tried `"~d" = (setMark:, moveToBeginningOfParagraphAndModifySelection:, moveToEndOfParagraphAndModifySelection:, delete:, yank:, insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:, yank:, swapWithMark:);` according to the post, and it didn't work either. `M-d` just doesn't do anything to me. :(